# Sending a email with pdf attachment from documents directory Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having issues getting my program to accept the path I gave it and returning it as `NSData`

```
    // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData


NSString *searchFilename = @"SafetyAuditReport.pdf"; // name of the PDF you are searching for

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

NSString *documentsSubpath;
while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
    if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
        continue;
    }

    NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
}

NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentsSubpath];


// Determine the MIME type
NSString *mimeType = @"application/pdf";




MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];
[mc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:mimeType fileName:@""];

NSLog(@"data was loaded......."); 
// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When ever the program gets the the emailing section it throws a nil exception for `addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:mimeType fileName:` saying the variable I gave it was `nil` (`pdfData`) when I know the file exists in the documents directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the debugger output and you should have a check for nil on the data before you do the send. if it's nil log the full path. let's see it.

Comment: Is `pdfData` really nil? The "file exists", please do `if(!pdfData){NSLog(@"pdfData is nil);}`, just to be sure. Also, you may need to put a `fileName`, just to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plz use this code

```
- (IBAction)sendMailWithAttachedFile
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    //    NSURL* outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self pathForResourse:fileName ofType:extension]];


    //Get the file path
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.pdf"];

    NSURL* outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:outputURL];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"data.pdf"];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];


}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i also found out that the problem was caused not because the file could not be found, the way i wrote my code  caused the email to try to send before the pdf file was generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we did it.....

```
         NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Name of File" ofType:@"pdf"];
     NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
     MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     mail.editing = YES;
     mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
     [mail setSubject:@"Your subject"];
     [pdfData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

     [mail addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"Name OF File.pdf"];

     [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
```